# How to open this ceiling lighting fixture to replace bulb

Tags: lighting

I have the ceiling lighting fixture you can see below. I am not sure how to open it. It does not screw or unscrew either way. It is not possible to push it or pull it.

It has two small holes that are not visible in this picture. The holes are about 120 degrees apart and are near the ceiling. The holes are large enough for a screwdriver to go in but when I did put one in I didn't feel it touching anything. I was able to use the screwdriver as a pry bar to separate the fixture from the ceiling for a few inches but I was afraid of breaking it if I went further. I am confused by the fact that there are two holes. Are you supposed to do both of them together? That would be extremely dangerous because you'd be certain to either fall down from the ladder or for the fixture to drop on your head.

Anyone has any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I would expect three holes.  Separating it a few inches should have been enough to at least see if something(springs) were inside holding it.  Most objects become loose if pried just 1/8 of an inch apart.

Comment: Have you tried using your hands to rotate the inner glass? Push your palm against the surface and twist CCW

Answer (score 1):

Some of these are on spring retainers, that you simply pull down to get into their extended position, then unclip to release the lightshade entirely. Can't vouch for whether that's how this model is set up.

Comment: Often, those spring retainers are much more stiff that you'd expect - they can take a pretty good tug. My bathroom vent fan cover is one example of that.